# creating a list of list objects terraform

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm setting up a terraform repo for my snowflake instance and bringing in a list of users to start managing.

I have a module called `users`

and have the following files:

[image]

I have a variable defined as follows.

```
variable "users" {

  type = list(object(
    {
      name                 = string
      comment              = string
      default_role         = string
      disabled             = bool
      must_change_password = bool
      display_name         = string
      email                = string
      first_name           = string
      last_name            = string
      default_warehouse    = string
    }
    )
  )
}
```

now inside `users.tf` I want to hold a list of all my users based on the above variable, I thought I could define it as follows:

```
users {
    user_1 = {
         name = 'x'

        }, 
    user_2 = {
         name = 'y'
        }
 }
```

however, when I run Terraform validate on this it gives me the error that a `user` block is not expected here.

Can someone tell me my error and give me some guidance if I'm doing this correctly?

My intention is to have a file to hold all my users that I then define with a dynamic block inside my `main.tf` file within this module.

I can then reference the dynamic block inside the `outputs.tf` which will give me access to the users inside said module in the global project namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like you are attempting to configuring your `users` as an object:

```
users {
  user_1 = {
    name = "x"
  },
  user_2 = {
    name = "y"
  }
}
```

but you actually set your variable constraint to a list of objects. So it should be:

```
users = [
  {
    name = "user_1"
    # other fields
  },
  {
    name = "user_2"
    # other fields
  }
]
```

---

Here is a full working example:

#### modules/users/variables.tf

```
variable "users" {
  type = list(object({
    name = string
  }))
}
```

#### modules/users/outputs.tf

```
output "users" {
  value = var.users
}
```

#### main.tf

```
module "users" {
  source = "./modules/users"

  users = [
    { name = "user_1" },
    { name = "user_2" }
  ]
}

output "users" {
  value = module.users.users
}
```

### plan output

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + users = [
      + {
          + name = "user_1"
        },
      + {
          + name = "user_2"
        },
    ]
```

Comment: awesome! this is close to my current approach, I'll have a play to see if I can get this working

Comment: Thanks for your help - after some testing and validation this helped. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your config syntax and usage is completely correct here. Your config file organization is the issue here. `users.tf` is a Terraform variables file, and therefore should have the `.tfvars` extension. If you rename the file from `users.tf` to e.g. `users.tfvars`, then you can specify it as an input with the `-var-file=users.tfvars` argument with the CLI or otherwise as per standard usage. You can see more information in the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#variable-definitions-tfvars-files).

On a side note: it is not really best practices to manage an entire module just for managing a set of users for a specific service. If you follow this design pattern in the future, then your codebase will not scale very well, and could easily become unmanageably large.

Comment: Thanks - knew I was messing up somewhere, as to my layout my use case is very specific. so don't think this will be too much of an issue! but thanks for your help!